# Return only array value in mongo projection

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to return only the value of a property in a mongodb projection?  For instance, I have a document that has a property whose value is an array.  I want the return object from a query to be the array only, not `property: [ .. ]`.  Example:

Document:

```
db.test.insert({ name: "Andrew",
   attributes: [ { title: "Happy"},
                 { title: "Sad" }
               ]
});
```

Query:

```
db.test.find({name: "Andrew"},{attributes:1, "_id":0});
```

That returns:

```
{ "attributes" : [ { "title" : "Happy" }, { "title" : "Sad" } ] }
```

I want it to return on the array:

```
[ { title: "Happy"},
  { title: "Sad" }
]
```

Is there a way to do that?  Thanks

Comment: Unfortauntely MongoDBs projection does not work like this server-side, you would need to filter this out client side

Comment: Thanks, that was my fear..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON doesn't allow the toplevel to be an array so a normal query doesn't allow this. You can however do this with the aggregation framework:

```
> db.test.remove();
> db.test.insert({ name: "Andrew", attributes: [ { title: "Happy"}, { title: "Sad" } ] });
> foo = db.test.aggregate( { $match: { name: "Andrew" } }, { $unwind: "$attributes" }, { $project: { _id: 0, title: "$attributes.title" } } );
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "title" : "Happy"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Sad"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
> foo.result
[ { "title" : "Happy" }, { "title" : "Sad" } ]
```

This however, does not create a cursor object that find does.

Comment: Thanks, I did have that suspicion that the array wasn't even valid JSON.  Thanks for the description!

Comment: A plain array is valid JSON – the various data types in JSON can all stand by themselves and make up a valid JSON document.

Comment: "JSON doesn't allow the toplevel to be an array" this is not true. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623339/is-a-list-array-valid-json