# Rails params: where did _json come from, and how do I whitelist it's contents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am writing a Rails API and attempting to create multiple records at the same time by passing a JSON array into the controller, like this:

```
[
    {
        "workflow_id": 1,
        "action": "Some Other Action",
        "order": 2,
        "notes": null
    },
    {
        "workflow_id": 1,
        "action": "Some Action",
        "order": 1,
        "notes": null
    }
]
```

When I view the parameters coming into the controller, this is what I see:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"_json"=>[{"workflow_id"=>1, "action"=>"Some Other Action", "order"=>2, "notes"=>nil}, {"workflow_id"=>1, "action"=>"Some Action", "order"=>1, "notes"=>nil}], "controller"=>"workflow_steps", "action"=>"update", "workflow_id"=>"1", "workflow_step"=>{}} permitted: false>
```

First of all, I'm unfamiliar with `_json`.  Is this a Rails convention for when an array is passed in?  I could not find any documentation on it.

Second, When I try this: `WorkflowStep.create(params[:_json])` I get the expected `ForbiddenAttributesError`.  But, I cannot figure out how to properly whitelist the json objects in my array.  I've tried these:

```
params.require(:_json).permit(_json: [:workflow_id, :action, :notes, :order])
params.permit(_json: [:workflow_id, :action, :notes, :order])
```

But I get this error: `undefined method` permit' for #Array:0x00007ffdeb0f8188`

I am unsure how to proceed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`params.require(:_json)` returns an array of `ActionController::Parameters` objects so you can whitelist using the code below:

```
params.require(:_json).map do |param| 
  param.permit(:workflow_id, :action, :order, :notes).to_h
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems it's a Rails feature, yet I haven't found any documentation for it. While parsing/decoding JSON, if it's not a hash (as JSON supports [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623339/is-a-list-array-valid-json) and even [strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json)) then it places inside `_json` key on the `params` object.

You can see the code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fce2f4cba385c6aa19d0b30b8daac8236ebbb97a/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L10-L15):

```rb
      DEFAULT_PARSERS = {
        Mime[:json].symbol => -> (raw_post) {
          data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(raw_post)
          data.is_a?(Hash) ? data : { _json: data }
        }
      }
```