# Using Mongo aggregate in meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a my collection as below:

```
id: 'some_id'
items: [ {name:x}, {name:y} ]
```

When I do `collection_object.find({id:'some_id'},{items:1,_id:0})` , it returns an object and not the actual array. Then I followed the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711816/return-only-array-value-in-mongo-projection) , and used the `aggregate` function in my Meteor helper, instead of find. The new call being:

```
collection_object.aggregate({$match:{id:'mseb'}}, {$unwind:'$items'} )
```

This raises the error that `aggregate` is undefined.

**Two questions:**
1. If the `find` call returns an object containing the array, how do I access individual elements of the array in the template. Using `{{this.items}}` shows an array of again, "objects", and `{{this.items.name}}` is undefined.
2. If not 1, then how to make `aggregate` work with meteor.

**Update:**
I followed the meteorhacks:aggregate approach, but that too gave the same result. The answer below worked for me.

Comment: Use the [**meteorhacks:aggregate**](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate) package that adds proper aggregation support for Meteor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can do:

`{{#each this.array}}
  {{name}}
 {{/each}`

tip: you can also do `collection.find().fetch()` it will return all matching documents as an Array. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch

2. Aggregate isn't supported yet in meteor you can add by doing `meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate`